# Ruby File.exists?() Failing on Network Drive

Tags: ruby, network-drive

I have an X:\ which is a network drive but when I run File.exists?(File path here) it returns false. when I run File.absolute_path(file path here) and set it to variable f then do File.exists?(f) that says false as well. I know the file exists and File.exists?() returns true when I try it on my C:. I'm not sure what is going on. Since it is a network drive maybe I don't have permissions?

Comment: Which os?
Can you see the file from UI?

Comment: Windows. I know the file exists. I can open it from folders.

Comment: It eventually calls C's `fstat` method. I'm not a windows guy, but my guess is fstat fails for whatever networking implementation you're using.  Try opening the file to read it and see if that succeeds.

Comment: 'X:\Development test files\RubyTestFile.xlsx' I have also tried 'X:\\Development test files\\RubyTestFile.xlsx'